# Passing Light but No Data

Tags: networking

Can anyone tell me what type of jumper I need to use when connecting single mode fiber to multi mode fiber? I have a run of multimode fiber that was extended with single mode. I have used both single and multimode jumpers but transmission is still too low to pass data.

Comment: You cannot do that. You must use single-mode end-to-end, or multi-mode end-to-end. The only way to do what you want is to put an active device that has both between the different links. For example, you could have a switch with a single-mode SFP and a multi-mode SFP.

Comment: Would a transceiver do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No amount of Cable Magic(tm) can make this work. A multi-mode signal is 50 or 62.5 micron. Fired into a single-mode 9 micron fiber, over 80% of the signal is instantly lost. Further loses will come from the SMF not being remotely designed for 850nm light, nor will the MM light be fired perfectly parallel into the fiber.

(With a "mode conditioning" cable, one can pass single-mode light across a short span of multi-mode fiber, but distance is significantly compromised, and there can only be one *continuous* MMF segment.)

Answer (score 6):

Going from multi-mode to single-mode fiber causes severe power loss or attenuation penalty, especially when not even a mode-conditioning patch cable is used (which is only possible on one end, not in between). On short runs this usually works but with more than a few (dozen) meters there's no chance.

(SMF can only propagate a single mode of the incoming light - all others are dropped - and its cross section is just 3% of MMF (9 µm vs 50 µm), so you lose some 10 dB.)

When the patch cable doesn't fit it needs to be exchanged. With deployed cable you need to use a media converter with appropriate interfaces/modules (e.g. 1000BASE-SX for MMF and 1000BASE-LX for SMF) and swap the transceivers on the end nodes.